# Meaning of Hadeeth?

Tags: quran, uloom-al-hadith, uloom-al-quran

Okay. Quick question. What is the meaning of [this hadeeth](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4984):-

"If you disagree with Zaid bin Thabit at any point in the Quran, write it in the dialect of Quraish, **verily the Quran was revealed in their tongue**"

Wasnt the Quran revealed in 7 different dialects at the same time? If so, if the Quran was revealed in the tongue of Quraish, where do the differences in dialects come from?

Comment: What is the source of the hadith quote and the translation? Note that according the definition that Hadith is what the prophet () said, did or remained silent upon this is not a hadith, but an athar because the statement was of 'Uthman () and the translation you shared is seemingly biased or based on one specific interpretation of his words. One must have in mind that the historical context was the creation of a standard scripture and not necessary on a specific tongue.

Comment: Sahih al-Bukhari 4987

Comment: Interestingly the translator used a different wording in a different chapter of [Sahih al-Bukhari 3506](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3506)

Comment: @Khizer Khan, take into account that there is a whole Sura, named Quraish (106), decicated for Quraish tribe.

Answer (score 1):

The Quran was originally revealed in the dialect of the Quraish since the preaching of Islam started with Quraish.

The seven dialects were revealed later on when Islam needed to spread among the different Arabs who needed different dialects.